# Is Agile a software development methodology?

Tags: agile, development-methodologies, waterfall, iterative-development

**Back ground:**

1)

*Waterfall model* has it's own phases of SDLC:

Requirements -> Design -> Implementation -> Verification -> Maintenance

2)

*Iterative model* has it's own phases of SDLC:

### [image]

---

But the term Agile does not have it's own development methodology. Agile projects are mostly [iterative in sofar](https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/iterative-development/#q=~(filters~(postType~(~'page~'post~'aa_book~'aa_event_session~'aa_experience_report~'aa_glossary~'aa_research_paper~'aa_video)~tags~(~'iterative*20development))~searchTerm~'~sort~false~sortDirection~'asc~page~1)) .

Is [Agile](https://www.agilealliance.org/agile101/the-agile-manifesto/) an effort planning tool and nothing more than that? Using scrum & kanban frameworks

Comment: Agile is a **management methodology** used primarily to manage the development of software.  Software developers naturally have a tendency to view things like Agile and DDD  from a code perspective, but that doesn't change their essential nature.

Comment: I've seen that question asked before a few weeks ago. The answer was, that Xtreme programming (which is another agile methodology) is more related to software development directly. I'll leave it to gnat to find the dupe :-).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Agile methodology in pure technical terms](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/368582/agile-methodology-in-pure-technical-terms)

Answer (score 5):

Agile did start as purely software development methodology, meant to fully replace waterfall and other process-heavy methodologies. All people who created [Agile Manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/) were either SW developers or managed software development projects. It even says "Working Software over comprehensive documentation". And it's [Agile Principles](http://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html) are clearly concerned with software development.

But then, it got taken over by Scrum, which is really just management methodology. Agile then began to be applied outside of software development.

Which is why Agile nowadays viewed as management methodology.

So answer to your question really depends on whenever you consider "Agile" as originally envisioned. Or "Agile" as it is understood and applied nowadays, which is basically just Scrum.

Comment: 1) Your referred agile principles does not explain the development life cycle. Looks like some recommendations. 2) Assuming Agile as originally envisioned, Is Agile a quickest waterfall? & Is waterfall a slower Agile? and that's the only difference

Comment: @user1787812 Agile principles do not explain "development life cycle" because Agile software development doesn't have "life cycle". All of the activities are done together, to the point it is hard to distinguish one from another. Activities like analysis, design, implementation and testing happen at the same time in true agile process. So answer to your second question is clear "No". Agile being just "repeated waterfall" is simplification meant to make it easier to explain (and sell) "Agile".

Comment: @user1787812 _"Is Agile a quickest waterfall? & Is waterfall a slower Agile?"_ The original proposal introduces kind of managable micro waterfalls, yes. The key software development methodology introduced those days was TDD.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What proposal are you talking about?

Comment: @Euphoric The Agile Manifesto as linked in the answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can you be more specific? Because to me, no such thing is there. It seems to me to be quite opposite. As focus on collaboration means minimal hand-offs, which is what phases "waterfall" are all about.

Comment: @Euphoric Are you convinced for *Agile being just "repeated waterfall"*, further those phases of waterfall can be followed randomly in Agile. Because analysis(is user stories), Testing(is stabilisation sprints), Operations(DevOps), Design &Coding(is mixed)

Comment: @user1787812 What you just describe is how Scrum mangled original Agile. Stabilisation sprints are terrible idea. User stories should be high-level "promises", which are then fleshed out by business-proxy during development, and DevOps should NOT be separate from development.

Comment: @Euphoric I said **micro waterfalls**. In practice it turned out, that every feature request and bug fix request had to follow a defined development cycle (e.g. User Story -> Rough Design -> Implementation -> Pass Tests -> Deliver). Unfortunately that didn't really fit well for ***all*** kinds of software.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "had to follow development cycle" because people working on the software were so used to waterfall, that adopting true agility requires massive shift in culture and skills. And that "Agile doesn't work for MY kind of software" is just crappy excuse.

Comment: @Euphoric OK, but, why reading those principles to follow Agile as originally envisioned, for a project, is still a challenge?

Comment: @user1787812 That is really complicated question, with answer being worthy of a book or two.

Comment: @Euphoric _"being worthy of a book or two"_ Not to mention, that there actually were some books published as follow up clarifications (e.g. by M. Fowler and K. Beck). Also the _wiki_ as internally linked up source of information, was becoming more popular at around the same time.

Comment: @Euphoric Well, the authors(that include developers) introducing Agile Principles, should have made the life easy, by explaining the idea behind those principles, that can be intuitive to use. Instead, of keeping those principles unused.

Comment: Allen talks more about [principles](https://youtu.be/vSnCeJEka_s?t=33m19s)

Answer (score 2):

Saying that waterfall has one set of SDLC phases and agile methods have their phases is incorrect.

Both plan-driven and adaptive methods are ways of looking at systems development. Regardless of which methodology you are using, you are going to do the same thing - initiate an effort or team, define some concept of what is being developed, plan out work, elicit and manage requirements, design solutions, integrate, and test solutions, deploy solutions and maintain them.

The difference between plan-driven methodologies and agile or adaptive methodologies is when these things occur. The agile methods acknowledge the fact that it's not possible to plan out and specify a project up-front thoroughly. By using short iterations and incrementally building a solution rather than creating a plan up-front and executing a project against it, you can adapt to changing needs.

Even characterizing Agile as "mini-waterfalls" is likely to be incorrect. The idea of a waterfall is that you, early in your project, have a fixed set of requirements. Taking Scrum as a specific example, your Sprint backlog isn't fixed at the beginning of a Sprint. You discover work, you negotiate with the Product Owner as you learn new information, and you work toward goals. You don't have a fixed set of requirements and design up-front, and you don't have a test and integration period in the end.

The Agile methods are a different perspective on managing the work that goes into a project, and a different set of principles that have been found to, generally speaking, work well when delivering software (and other types of products or services, in some cases).

Comment: _"Taking Scrum as a specific example, your Sprint backlog isn't fixed at the beginning of a Sprint."_ Well, please note that "Kanban" won't work well with the essential "Kaizen", which introduces at least a temporary limitaiton.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Uhm...what? Kaizen is an improvement activity. The Kanban Method (or Kanban Methodology) introduces WIP limits. Do note that Kanban and the Kanban Method are different.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write _**without** the essential "Kaizen"_. I only argued this should have been mentioned.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You can use Kanban without Kaizen. However, Kaizen is part of the Kanban Method and various Lean methods. Note the difference between [Kanban, the lean manufacturing practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban) and [Kanban, the methodology popularized by David J. Anderson and others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban_(development)).

Answer (score 1):

"Agile" is an adjective; not a noun. We want to write applications in an effective fashion, but that doesn't mean "Effective" is a software development model. Likewise, "Agile" isn't one either. So no, "Agile" is not a software development methodology.

The most common way of developing an application in an agile fashion is to use an iterative development model. However, not all iterative development models are particularly agile. Scrum for example is a highly proscriptive model if followed to the letter, which is ironic as "Scrum" and "Agile" are often mistakenly assumed to be synonymous.

The less rules a model has, and the more it can be readily changed to adapt to circumstances, the more agile a model is. So models can be agile (or not), but there is no "Agile model".

Comment: Iterative development encompasses pretty much all development methodologies. You can add multiple waterfalls back to back and suddenly you have an iterative development process. The difference between agile methodologies and others is that it is also incremental, which paired with iterative process is not sustainable in other methodologies.

Answer (score -1):

"Agile" means nothing in and of itself. It's just a buzzword for a wide range of development and organisational strategies.

These range from (as we say in the Netherlands) "let's all party and have a good time" with no organisation, quality control, or processes in place whatsoever, to more rigidly self organising teams like scrum and kanban.

As you compare these more advanced and involved agile methods to waterfall, you'll see striking similarities, where quite often each scrum sprint for example may well be organised pretty much like a very compressed waterfall release cycle, with analysis, implementation, testing, and documentation phases (though these tend to run side by side to a degree in scrum sprints).

What you often won't find is entire dedicated teams doing only one thing, like a specialised test team and a specialised architecture team, but rather the people will be spread out over the various scrum teams (however larger organisation will often have multiple parallel structures with for example testers belonging not just to their scrum teams but also to a central test group where scrum teams can request test capacity as needed and have it assigned from the pool of available testers).